# javalangClassFormatError: Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18

Tags: apache, ant, jenkins

i just comitted a new version of my code into my git repository and pushed it to the server. jenkins started to build my tests as expected but suddenly failed with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.constantpool.ConstantPoolEntry.readEntry(ConstantPoolEntry.java:159)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.constantpool.ConstantPool.read(ConstantPool.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.AntAnalyzer.determineDependencies(AntAnalyzer.java:92)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.depend.AbstractAnalyzer.getClassDependencies(AbstractAnalyzer.java:100)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.Depend.determineDependencies(Depend.java:346)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.Depend.execute(Depend.java:718)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:302)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:221)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

(see answer for solution)

greetz,
nico

Comment: You need to put more details about the problem, so that people know what answer you looking for.

Answer (score 6):

after a day of following different traces i found a solution and just wanted to post it here if someone runs into the same trouble.

- the ant version (1.8.2.) i was using was too old to handle CONSTANT_INVOKEDYNAMIC (Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18) which in my understanding means that ant discovered some java 8 lamda code which it can't handle

  - i have already been using lambdas before that certain commit! so why does it complain about it now?
  - googleing lead me to a bug in ant 1.8.2 which produced exactly this error. i was sceptic since i didn't downgrade my ant installation on the server and 10 minutes ago the build went fine - with 1.8.2!

so i started solving pragmatically:

- downloaded ant 1.9.5, untared it somewhere
- renamed the old ant command (/usr/bin/ant => /usr/bin/ant-1.8.2)
- linked the new ant to /usr/bin/ant

and then everything worked fine!

after this odyssey, does anybody have an idea why this error didn't appear earlier?

Comment: This issue was fixed in Ant 1.9.0 (https://github.com/apache/ant/commit/b103f7e3). It probably occurred because the JDK on the Jenkins server was upgraded.